# Maven Build Failure due Plugin Dependency

Tags: maven, tomcat8, liferay-7

I've read the following previous answers to similar topics, but none have worked for me.

Here is what I've tried:
[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie)

[Maven Build Failure - failure to find plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220960/maven-build-failure-failure-to-find-plugins)

The first link doesn't really apply because I'm not using a proxy, but I did check the settings.xml file for other possibilities. I can download directly by going to the plugin .jar file.

The second link might apply, but I have no idea what they mean by: "change user settings to point out to correct settings.xml and to your repository folder should exist in your system." I don't know how to do this and am not sure which repository they are referring to and how I find out. I'm looking only at my Maven settings.xml file.

So here's my errors

```
    C:\cas-overlay-template-master>mvn package install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cas-overlay 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.3/maven-compiler-plugin-3.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.965 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-21T23:42:13-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/97M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

My goal is to get CAS 5.0.4 working for a Liferay 7.0ga3, running Tomcat 8, JDK 1.8, and Maven 3. I am a student, have never used any of these technologies except JDK 1.8, so I really need very understandable answers. Not veteran answers for those that should know what they are doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem here is around the certificates the Maven JVM is trusting:

> Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
>   the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Various things can fix it, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty/25188331#25188331) has a lot of solutions (and one more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788295/maven-error-repeated-java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-tr)).

Comment: I don't know how to just reply instead of comment, but I am running WIndows Student edition. The Unix/Linux shell commands don't help me. What is the equillivant to: 
cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)/jre/lib/security   
ln -fsh /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts

Further, when I look in my setttings.xml, I don't see any reference to the trust/key store at all. How do I add it and will I just references my JDK 1.8 /security/cacerts/*.jks file?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788295/maven-error-repeated-java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-tr

Is the solution to just point the MAVEN_OPTS to my jdk1.8/security/cacerts directory?

Comment: Do you have any special certificates required for where you are (e.g. a corporate/university proxy)?

Comment: No special certificates. I'm a student working on a home computer.

Comment: I did try adding MAVEN_OPTS pointing to my cacerts file in the JDK; however, I received an error that says:

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program

I had forgotten to start up my Liferay Tomcat, maybe that's why; I'm doing that now, but it takes about one hour for the Tomcat to load and Lifray localhost to load! I have asked for support on the Liferay forums regarding the VERY slow starup, but have not had any success yet.

Comment: Any time you see an error talking about "C:\Program", you should put double quotes around the complete path (").

Comment: Which path though because I'm not typing a path. I'm in the directory and running mvn package install. Do you mean to put double quotes around the path in the environment variable path?